# iat not performing correctly when DataFrame is a class variable

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: I'm using Pandas version 0.20.3

I have a class instance that contains a Pandas DataFrame. I want to modify the DataFrame using `.iat` but it does not perform as expected.

Here is what I would expect and what happens if I use a DataFrame outside of the class:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, index=[0])
df.c.iat[0] = 1
df
```

returns

```
   a  b  c
0  0  0  1
```

as you would expect.

However, if I use `myclass.df` instead:

```
myclass.df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, index=[0])
myclass.df.c.iat[0] = 1
myclass.df
```

returns

```
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
```

Even more confusingly,

```
print(myclass.df.c.iat[0])
```

returns `1`. So this does not seem to be a copy vs. view error. If I replace the `.iat` with `.iloc`, then the value is being set correctly.

Is this a bug in Pandas or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It works fine on my side ... just do not name a df have dot in it  ...

Comment: I had mistakenly put ```iloc``` instead of ```iat``` in the question. Edited now. Does it still work for you?

Comment: still work for me

Comment: "just do not name a df have dot in it" -  What do you mean?

Comment: `class MyClass: pass` ... `myclass = MyClass()` ... `myclass.df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, index=[0])` ... `myclass.df.c.iat[0] = 1` works on Pandas 0.23.2

Comment: Does your actual code do every access on the `myclass` class and not on an instance of that class by accident? Is it always `myclass.df` and never `myclass().df` (or equivalent instance attribute access)?

Comment: @kristaps No, that never happened.